# Segmentation fault with 3-dimensional malloc'ed array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I C code compile and exit, I get a segmentation fault. When I tried to run GDB, the result is as follows:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400998 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe208) at test.c:107
```

The line in question:

```
if((p_l2p[p_bp][p_rp][p_cp] & FULL) == 0)
```

The variable declaration:

```
unsigned long long ***p_l2p; //Primary L2P[P_Bank][Row][Cas]
p_l2p = (unsigned long long ***)malloc(sizeof(int **)*P_BANK);

for(i=0;i<P_BANK;i++) // set s[P_Bank][Row]
{
    p_l2p[i] = (unsigned long long **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*ROW);         

    for(j=0;j<ROW;j++) // set s[P_Bank][Row][CAS]
    {
        p_l2p[i][j] = (unsigned long long *)malloc(sizeof(int)*CAS);

    }
}

int p_bp; //Bank Point
int p_rp; //Row Point
int p_cp; //Cas Point
```

(Note that the P_BANK value is 4, the ROW value is 8192, and the Column value is 128.)

The problem is when I try to print the point where the segmentation fault is through GDB as below.
(We confirmed that the value causing the segment fault is p_l2p [2] [15] [80].)

The point where the segment fault is p_l2p [2] [15] [80] is one of the arrays declared as dynamic memory allocation by code. I tried to print those variables using GDB's print function. Oddly, there are values ​​of p_l2p [2] [14] [x] and p_l2p [2] [16] [x], but only values ​​corresponding to p_l2p [2] [15] [x] do not exist.

What is the cause of this segmentation fault?

Comment: If `p_l2p` is defined as a pointer to `unsigned long long` (usually 8 bytes) why when mallocing you give it `sizeof(int)` (usually 4 bytes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the cause of this segmentation fault?

Insufficient memory allocated.

Size of an `int` is less than the size of `unsigned long long` here. [@SHG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321743/segmentation-fault-with-3-dimensional-malloced-array#comment87659390_50321743)

---

Avoid size calculation  errors - of which there is 1, the inner most.

Allocate to the size of the object, not the type.

```
the_type_is_irrelevant ***p_l2p;

// p_l2p = (unsigned long long ***)malloc(sizeof(int **)*P_BANK);
p_l2p = malloc(sizeof *p_l2p * P_BANK);

for(i=0; i<P_BANK; i++) {
    // p_l2p[i] = (unsigned long long **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*ROW);         
    p_l2p[i] = malloc(sizeof p_l2p[i][0] * ROW);         

    for(j=0; j<ROW; j++) {
        // p_l2p[i][j] = (unsigned long long *)malloc(sizeof(int)*CAS);
        p_l2p[i][j] = malloc(sizeof p_l2p[i][j][0]* CAS);

    }
}
```

---

Note: Even the size of `int *` may differ from `unsigned long long *`, although that is rare.  Best to not assume all pointer types share the same size.  The most common difference, when there is one, is between pointers to objects and pointers to functions.

---

Casts are not needed here.

Robust code would also check the allocation result.

```
p_l2p = malloc(sizeof *p_l2p * P_BANK);
if (p_l2p == NULL && P_BANK > 0) {
  Handle_Out_of_Memory();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!